# Ordering elements by number in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorting

how could I arrange the following div's by the value in the attribute amount with jquery? Thanks.

```
<a href="#" id="id1" class="lTest" amount="12">
    <div>abcd1</div>
<a/>

<a href="#" id="id2" class="lTest" amount="64">
    <div>abcd2</div>
<a/>

<a href="#" id="id3" class="lTest" amount="32">
    <div>abcd3</div>
<a/>

<a href="#" id="id4" class="lTest" amount="8">
    <div>abcd4</div>
<a/>
```

Comment: Why have `<div>` tags inside of `<a>` tags?

Comment: Hi, the links will contain a large number of objects. That shouldn't make a difference for sorting, should it?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, no, but `<a>` is generally regarded as an inline element whereas `<div>` is a block-level element.  You may get some funny behavior from the browser trying to render this.

Comment: wtf is the amount paramer in a a tag. This isnt valid html. Ive newer sag  something like this <a href="#" id="id1" class="lTest" amount="32"> <----- look at amount="32" is that valid? i think no!

Comment: Anchor tags must contain inline elements per spec.

Comment: @streetparade Additional attributes are allowed per spec, provided you include your own DTD and namespace. In most cases it will not hurt anything however since the data in the attributes is ignored.

Comment: HTML allows you to add your own attributes into tags, there's no downside to it.

Comment: I'm willing to bet the reason none of these answers seem to be working for you is exactly because of `<div>` inside of `<a>` weirdness.  Try removing the `<div>` and I bet it works.

Comment: You also might want to change the closing tag to `</a>`.  The browser might interpret `<a/>` to be a completely separate, self-closing anchor tag.

Comment: @Tiniser, thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that but it doesn't seem to work. Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, I tested my answer.  I also have no reason to believe the other answers are untested.  What didn't work was when I tried it with your markup as given: the browser rendered the `<a>`, `<div>` and another `<a>` as sibling elements, instead of having `<div>` as a child of `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='jquery.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(init);

            function init() {
                var parent = $('#someid');
                var children = $('a', parent);
                children.sort(function(a, b) {
                   return parseInt($(a).attr('amount')) - parseInt($(b).attr('amount'));
                })
                $.each(children, function(i, child) {
                    parent.append(child);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="someid">
            <a href="#" class="lTest" amount="12"><div>abcd2</div></a>
            <a href="#" class="lTest" amount="64"><div>abcd4</div></a>
            <a href="#" class="lTest" amount="32"><div>abcd3</div></a>
            <a href="#" class="lTest" amount="8"><div>abcd1</div></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Edit] Replaced by a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to prove it's working. I've changed x in abcdx to the expected ordering. You should end up with abcd1, abcd2, abcd3 and abcd4 in this order.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Considering several helpful people commented and I haven't been able to get any of it to work, I'm assuming the problems on my end. @BalusC, have you tested the above code with with the markup I posted. Did it work? Thanks.

Comment: You used <a/> to close <a> tags. This is wrong. Fix it first.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure the other examples would work too were it not for some strange problem with my pc. Thanks everyone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var links = $('a.lTest').sort( function(a,b) { return $(a).attr('amount') - $(b).attr('amount'); } );

for ( var i = 1; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    links.eq(i-1).insertBefore( links.eq(i) );
}
```

Comment: I ran the code and firebug tells me $("a.lTest").sort is not a function

Comment: I've been able to run sort on jQuery objects fine.  What about if you try `jQuery("a.lTest").sort(...)`?

Comment: Still the same error, thanks the help but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think this is realy a stupid question. take a answer and stick with it. Thast my opinion. Every answer here would work, but you are not able to test it, nor give more information what you realy need. And doing some jquery function calls without giving an id as paramater will never work. On your code i saw no where an id, jusa$t a class lTest.

Comment: I've tested everyone of the suggestions they just don't seem to work. But i've taken your suggestion and added id's if that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

first, assume the  tags are surrounded by a div (id ="testDiv")

Sorry, my initial way of doing this is wrong...

DO NOT DO THIS: BROKEN!!! (See edit below)

var testDiv = $('#testDiv');
  var children = testDiv.children('.lTest');
  children.each(function() {$(this).remove();});
  var testArray = $.makeArray(children);
  testArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseInt($(a).attr('amount')) - parseInt($(b).attr('amount');
  });

children.each(function() {testDiv.append(this);});

EDIT: THIS IS WORKING VERSION:

```
var testDiv = $('#testDiv');
var children = testDiv.children('.lTest').remove();

children = children.sort(function(a,b){
  return parseInt($(a).attr('amount')) - parseInt($(b).attr('amount'));
});

testDiv.append(children);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I ran the code with the elements inside the #testDiv you suggested but it still doesn't work. I cannot figure out what i'm missing. Did you test the code on your system?

Comment: whoops, my bad, I was running off of what I remembered writing before... I will edit with working example.

Answer (score 0):

Your first comment on Tinister's answer indicates that your test page doesn't know anything about JQuery.  Make sure you are properly including JQuery in your tests and that the HTML is correctly constructed.  Then you will probably find that one of the other answers works.

John